# How to redirect to application page after installing application to one's page or app?

Tags: facebook

Now I want to automatic redirect to facebook application's index page after user installing the application to his/her facebook page.

My method is use the href tag as below:

```
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=".$APPID."&pages&perms=publish_stream&page=".$paID."' target='_top'>Add APP</a>
```

I have tried some ways such as add redirect_uri or next or post_authorize_redirect_url as parameter to the add.php link,but they all redirected to the facebook page or application after installing.

Then how to realize it?

## Useful link

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

I know that it can redirect after authentication.Such as:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token
```

But what is after installing?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're doing?

Comment: I think you can set callback url on facebook api setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
```

Client ID is your app id
Redirect uri is your callback page

For more you can look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) page

Comment: Thank you.But my question was not oauth.It was add app.The url is: http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_ID&pages&perms=publish_stream&page=PAGE_ID

Comment: It's all same you can look at authentication informations from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin here. Redirect uri will ok for you!

Comment: You are still don't use redirect_uri parameter. you have to add &redirect_uri=YourURL what is next btw?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the API to add the app to the page?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Comment: Thank you for answering me.Do you mean I should use /PAGE_ID/tabs? When I tried it,I printed the array and it returned 1.I can't see any tab information.Why?

Comment: Are you using a page access token?

Comment: /PAGE_ID/tabs?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN is not work,but /PAGE_ID?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN can work

Comment: I was successful by this way!From here I can know whether my app is in the user's pages and apps.But how to redirect after installing?

Comment: The same way you'd do any javascript redirect in your app i guess? window.location= new url?